# How can I lock the wait and notify and sync them from different projects?

Tags: java, android, wait

I'm writing an android app with java, using a server side written also in java.
In my server side project I have a Client and a Group classes. Lets say there are 2 clients, so each device is a client, and they are in the same group. After some activity finished, I call a function through the Client (server side) which receive an integer. I want to check which of the clients has a bigger integer, so I check it in the group.

The thing I want to do is to return to each device the result "winner" or "loser" according to their integer. I call a function from the group instance to calculate the winner. I want the clients to wait until the calculation is complete, and then send the result to the device (client side).

How can I set the client to wait and get notified from the group singleton? Remember that there are 2 different clients, each client for a different device, so they run on different threads.

This is what I written, and what happens is after the activity is finished and I call the function to calculate the winner, the loser gets notified (in the device) but the winner is in a wait state.

Client:

```
                    score = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("score")
                            .toString());

                    mGroup.calcResult();
                    while (result == null) {
                        lock.lock();
                        try {
                            System.out.println("waiting");
                            groupReady.await();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            lock.unlock();
                        }
                    }
```

Group:

```
public void calcResult() {
    finishedClients++;
    if (finishedClients == clients.size())
        pCalcResult();
}

private void pCalcResult() {
    finishedClients = 0;
    int minScore = clients.get(0).getScore();
    int clientIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {
        if (clients.get(i).getScore() < minScore) {
            minScore = clients.get(i).getScore();
            clientIndex = i;
            clients.get(i).setResult("winner");
        }
    }

    clients.get(clientIndex).setResult("looser");

    lock.lock();
    try {
        groupReady.signalAll();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }

}
```

I think what is happening is that the winner result is null, so he enters the loop (client) and the group thread notify before the winner call await.

How can I fix it?

Comment: How do you actually communicate between server and client? Your client is an android device, right?

Comment: yes my client is an android device and the communication is through sockets. But the client in the question is in the server side, it represents the clients connected to the server

Comment: Btw what is actually the error/exception?

Comment: There is no exception or error, the winner is just waiting instead of running.

Comment: So did you try to run the client threads BEFORE the server thread, so you can be sure, that your clients ARE waiting for notify?

Comment: I printed the client state when he was not responding, and I found out he is still running, but waiting.

Comment: If you start the calculation and call .signallall before the client call .await, how should the client get the notification?

Comment: Well that is the problem, how can I promise that all the clients call await before the notifyall apply?

Comment: Try to lock before setting or checking the result

Comment: didn't help... I followed some printing I inserted and I found out that the client that enter the wait, is getting notified before applying the await

Answer (score 0):

```
public void calcResult() {
    finishedClients++;
    if (finishedClients == clients.size()) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pCalcResult();
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
}    

private void pCalcResult() {
        finishedClients = 0;
        int minScore = clients.get(0).getScore();
        int highestScore = minScore;
        int clientIndex = 0;
        // So I'm not sure what you want to do here. 
        //If you only expect 2 clients ever then why the for loop? And if you are                
        //expecting more then 2 clients then you code will never work..So ill
        //assume you expect more then 2 clients.
        //You can start at 1 because you already have the values of 0. Which also will
        //be the default winner if all the scores are equal.
        for (int i = 1; i < clients.size(); i++) {
            //So if the score is lower then the current minscore..
            if (clients.get(i).getScore() < minScore) {
                minScore = clients.get(i).getScore();
            } else if (clients.get(i).getScore > highestScore) {
                highestScore = clients.get(i).getScore();
                // Remember who the highestScore had so we can mark it as winner.
                clientIndex = i;
            }
            // They are all loosers till we find the actual winner..
            clients.get(i).setResult("looser");
        }

        clients.get(clientIndex).setResult("winner");

        lock.lock();
        try {
            groupReady.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I dont mind of the winner, just the loser. And yes, in the future I will work with more than 2 clients. But for now lets assume that there are only 2, just to see it work. The problem is not fixed yet, because the client might be awaiting instead of running, as I explained in the question. Any idea of a way to wait & notify between different objects and devices?

Comment: Check the edited calcResult method in the code I posted.

Comment: If I understand this http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/locks.html correctly a Thread calling lock.lock() and then enter a method calling lock.lock() again before an unlock was called will block.

Comment: @Joel the await call on the Condition will release the lock, so its not the problem